# Notation for working with multiple probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

Say I have a random variable $X$, and two probability measures $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$. The standard notation for the pdf of $X$ is just $f_X(x)$. Does there exist any notation, or could anyone suggest some notation, for distinguishing between the pdf of $X$ under $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$ respectively?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are absolutely continuous with respect to each other? Otherwise the question does not seem well-defined.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\{X\in dx\}$?

Comment: Why do  we need absolute continuity of P and Q?

Comment: Yes, they are absolutely continuous.

Comment: But  why is it necessary?

Comment: I am working with martingale changes of measure for a branching process, and need notation for the pdf of $X$ under both measures.

Comment: The distributions of $X$ under $P$ and $Q$ are $P_X$ and $Q_X$ respectively. There is no canonical notation for the densities $dP_X(x)/dx$ and $dQ_X(x)/dx$ that I am aware of but it might suffice to introduce them by stating that $dP_X(x)=f_X(x)dx$ and $dQ_X(x)=g_X(x)dx$.

Comment: @Wolfups I could not comment  for  this specific problem but in general when two different measures are defined on  the  outcomes of an experiment is not necessary that they are abs. cont.   For instance in the  most  trivial case :  Toss of two coins, one fair the other both sides show head. Here, X=1 if H , X=0 if T. P(X=0)=P(X=1)=1/2.  Q(X=1)=1.  Are they absolutely cont.?   Measures are singular. I am sure  less trivial examples can be   constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the $f$ in $f_X(x)$ carries no information other than saying: "This is a pdf with respect to Lebesgue measure on ${\mathbb R}$." Therefore you could say:

Let $f_X$ and $g_X$ be the pdfs of $X$ with respect to the probability measures $P$ and $Q$.